# factors to consider before dropping a column from a table

Tags: java, database, jdbc

We are supporting deletion of columns from a table through java layer. What are the factors that should be considered before doing so like
1.no of instances in table
2.behavior of different database vendors etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

constraints on the columns. If you have PKs or FKs on the columns then they may not (or cannot) be dropped (easily) depending on db vendor. While the cols may not be 'used' by the user, they may be dependent on by other cols/tables.
Also, total agree with duffymo. VERY dangerous to allow users to chose to drop cols.
Oracle does have the ability to restore dropped cols, but really, do you want to go down that path?
Auto generated drop statements have always been fraught with peril.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you're doing the right thing? Unless you're using throwaway tables for people to mess around with or use for studying, this sounds like a not so good design.

Once tables are defined, their column number shouldn't change. Otherwise you'd get denormalized tables; foreign keys can break and all hell breaks loose unless you've got pretty good constraints placed on your columns.

Tracking what columns exist and what queries you can execute will put much more burden on your JDBC code than needed.

This isn't a Java or JDBC question, it's more of a database design question. You should speak with your DBA about this.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest question has little to do with the database and everything to do with clients that use it.  Your Java app might be able to check to see if there are any non-null entries in the column, but it can't tell which clients are expecting the column to be there for SELECTs and UPDATEs.

I don't know your precise use case, but I'd say this is usually an activity for a DBA and not a user of your app.  I'd advise caution.

Comment: The use case involves removing columns that are not required anymore and so we are guaranteed that query exists involving that column.However i am concerned about the factors that should be considered like if the delete should be queued if there are a large number of rows etc

Comment: Still wrong.  This is something that should be done in a database management console by a DBA, not your application code.  I challenge the idea that users and your code can "know" that a column isn't required anymore.  Sounds like a design that should be reexamined to me.